# Trying to recreate this piece of code from JS in C++

Tags: javascript, c++

I've watched a course on Dynamic Programming and the instructor solved the problem like this, in JS.

I understood the logic, but now I have to write it in C++. Here's his code:

[image: photo]

I'm trying to transition to C++ but I'm thrown off by some errors:

```
std::vector<int> howSum(std::vector<int> numbers, int target)
{
    if (target == 0) return std::vector<int>();
    if (target < 0) return NULL; /*this doesn't work here because NULL is of type int - what should I do?*/

    for (int num : numbers)
    {
        int remainder = target - num;
        std::vector<int> remainderResult = howSum(numbers, remainder);
        if (remainderResult != NULL) /*doesn't work*/
        {
            return remainderResult.push_back(num);
        }
    }

    return NULL; /*doesn't work*/
}
```

I don't really know how I should return null and compare to null like he does in JS and I think that's the main problem for my code.

How can I do that?

Comment: If your compiler is at least c++17, make the return type `std::optional<std::vector<int>>` .

Comment: @Eugene it doesn't work or I'm not doing it properly - can you show me how to do it? Btw, I'm using VS 2019 Community.

Comment: @Eugene nevermind, I changed my compiler to c++17 and it's working :) thanks

Comment: I did not mean `std::optional` to be *the only* change. If it compiles now, that may not be enough. Please study std::optional.

Comment: @Eugene I don't really seem to be able to do it myself, to be honest. I've tried changing it as you said, but now I get another error saying that I can't use .push_back() (because I changed the type to std::optional<std::vector<int>>). Would you mind writing that piece of code from JS in C++? I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, C++ variables cannot hold value of `null`. `NULL` is not a replacement for it - this is just a fancy way to write `0`. Starting from C++17, the standard library has a template for a nullable type: `std::optional` (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)). Its syntax partly imitates pointers.

Also, `push_back()` does not return the resulting vector, the `return` must be split into a separate statement.

With these changes, your source should look like:

```
std::optional<std::vector<int>> howSum(std::vector<int> numbers, int target)
{
    if (target == 0) return std::vector<int>();
    if (target < 0) return std::nullopt; 

    for (int num : numbers)
    {
        int remainder = target - num;
        std::optional<std::vector<int>> remainderResult = howSum(numbers, remainder);
        if (remainderResult != std::nullopt) 
        {
            remainderResult->push_back(num);
            return remainderResult;
        }
    }

    return std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: It's working after your edit. Thanks a lot for your time. I'll look into std::optional :)

Comment: Is there any way to display the result of this function like console.log did in JS? I've tried calling it like this std::cout<<howSum(numbers, 7); and I get "no operator "<<" matches these operands". (numbers was already defined, I just didn't include it here).

Comment: You have to write your own loop for printing.

Comment: Yep, I expected that, but I didn't know how. I realised that I need to store the value of the call into another variable like this - std::vector<int> vector = howSum(numere, 7).value(); then iterate through it. Thanks a lot for your answers, they really help me learn something new.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu You can do it without the copy, as long as you're mindful of the `std::optional` "layer", which you have to be anyway as there may not _be_ a value!

Comment: `auto remainderResult` would be well justified here, and make the code more readable.